# preg_match regex with fix character in the middle

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using `preg_match` to find two letters and 4-6 digits, but there should be a hyphen `-` character in the middle. I'm starting from there:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\W[0-9]{4,6}$/"...
```

I came out with this solution, where I use `\W` as an any "non-word" character.
But I know it will be a hyphen, so I would like to be more specific.

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{2}.-.[0-9]{4,6}$/"...
```

Comment: Replace `\W` with `-`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you need to check if the whole string **is** two letters, an hyphen, and 4-6 digits, or do you need to **find** a substring of two letters, an hyphen, and 4-6 digits in a larger string? It isn't a bad idea to write an example string in your question.

Comment: yes, that's the point.
I think my description covered it. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

wow, Wiktor Stribiżew's answer was it.
I didn't know it was so easy...

so it's

if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{4,6}$/"...

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to replace `\W` with a *fixed character*:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z]{2}-\d{4,6}$/i"...
```